# Control is going without execution of codes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am calling an function `getRideBookedDetails()` from `onCreate()` to get the details from Firebase Realtime Database. I am also able to get the data from firebase and printing it on logcat. But the control flow is not going in from Top to Bottom manner instead it goes at the end without execution of few line of code.

Please see in function, till this code executing fine but after this last if block gets executed and pop up a Toast as per code:

```
                                println(toAddressFB)
                                println(toAddressFB)
                                println(date)
                                println(time)
                                println(noOfSeats)
                                println(noOfSeatsBooked)
```

Function:

```
private fun getRideBookedDetails() {
       // boolean variable to show error msg only one time
       var msgShowNew = true

        val getDataReference = mDatabase.getReference("Find_ride")
        getDataReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("Get Data Error:", "getDataReference:onCancelled", p0.toException())
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {


                println(p0)
                println("children: " + p0.children)
                println("key: " + p0.key)
                println("value: " + p0.value)


                var sno = 0
                // creating for loop to get data until ends
                for (data in p0.children) {

                    // creating hashmap to get each value inside children separately using hash key
                    val hashMap = data.value as HashMap<String, Any>
                    //println("Ride By UID "+hashMap["ridebookedByUserID"])

                    if (hashMap.size > 0) {
                        if (hashMap["ridebookedByUserID"]!!.equals(storedUID)) {
                            sno++

                            val rideCreatedKeyRef = hashMap["createRideKeyRef"]
                            val noOfSeatsBooked = hashMap["numOfSeatRequired"]
                            //println("Ride created key Ref: " + rideCreatedKeyRef)
                            //println("Seats: " + noOfSeatsBooked)
                            // getting ride created by user data using uid
                            val getUserData = mDatabase.reference.child("Create_ride/$rideCreatedKeyRef")
                            getUserData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
                                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                                    Log.w("Get Data Error:", "getData:onCancelled", p0.toException())
                                }

                                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                                    // getting value using hash map keys, key in ["..."] should be same as created // uncomment above printline to know key or see Firebase
                                    val fromAddressFB = p0.child("fromaddress").value.toString()
                                    val toAddressFB = p0.child("toaddress").value.toString()
                                    val date = p0.child("ridestartdate").value.toString()
                                    val time = p0.child("ridestarttime").value.toString()
                                    val noOfSeats = p0.child("noofseatsmax").value
                                    val noOfFilledSeats = p0.child("nooffilledseats").value

                                    println(fromAddressFB)
                                    println(toAddressFB)
                                    println(date)
                                    println(time)
                                    println(noOfSeats)
                                    println(noOfSeatsBooked)
**Till here code execution perfectly then control is going to if(msgShowNew == true) { ... }**
============================================================================


                                    // binding data to class rideDetails
                                    val ride = rideDetails()        // rideDetails is class which is used to transport data/bind data
                                    ride.sno = sno
                                    ride.rideFrom = fromAddressFB
                                    ride.rideTo = toAddressFB
                                    ride.rideDate = date
                                    ride.rideTime = time
                                    ride.numOfRider = noOfSeatsBooked!!
                                    rideDetails.add(ride)

                                    msgShowNew = false
                                }

                            })
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(msgShowNew == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You have not created/taken any ride yet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                // turning off visibility of progress bar
                rideHistoryProgressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })
    }
```

Logcat

```
08-31 19:07:24.314 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Find_ride, value = {-LnbnXT1NYY9ghXsMbN6={ridebookedByUserID=8CX0A7Z8FLbPGVQuIrk2ZtLgl4n2, createRideKeyRef=-Lnbn5uj5LUjtY2LafdM, numOfSeatRequired=2}} }
08-31 19:07:24.314 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: children: com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1@ebe9b5
08-31 19:07:24.315 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: key: Find_ride
08-31 19:07:24.315 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: value: {-LnbnXT1NYY9ghXsMbN6={ridebookedByUserID=8CX0A7Z8FLbPGVQuIrk2ZtLgl4n2, createRideKeyRef=-Lnbn5uj5LUjtY2LafdM, numOfSeatRequired=2}}
08-31 19:07:24.717 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: Block E, Shyam Vihar Phase-1, Najafgarh, Delhi, 110043, India
08-31 19:07:24.717 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: Pocket 7, Sector 12 Dwarka, Dwarka, New Delhi, Delhi 110075, India
08-31 19:07:24.718 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: 31/08/2019
08-31 19:07:24.718 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: 21:30
08-31 19:07:24.718 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: 4
08-31 19:07:24.718 28261-28261/com.example.carpooleasy I/System.out: 2
```

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. While the data is being loaded, you main code continues to executed. Then when the data is available from the server, your `onDataChange` method is called. This means that any code that needs the data from the server, must be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen After the println(noOfSeatsBooked) you can see the code is in onDataChange method so it should be also in execution. But it my case it is not..

Comment: From the comment you now left in the code it seems that you expect `if(msgShowNew == true)` to execute after all of `onDataChange` has run. This is simply not the case. The `onDataChange` runs independently of any of your other code, so you should simply not have any implicit dependencies between the blocks. That's why the answer I linked shows how to make an explicit dependency, by introducing a custom callback to ensure you control the order in which the code blocks are executed.